# node canvas getImageData() out of memory

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory, getimagedata, node-canvas

I have a nodejs application that transforms images.
I run my application in pm2 with 32gb of ram.
When trying to get the image data of an image i am getting this error.
I have tried to increase the node js memory limit using --max-old-space-size
tried to increase it to 8192 as well as 32678 but it I still get an error.

```
 m[9161:0x41069d0]    18179 ms: Mark-sweep 22.3 (29.2) -> 22.0 (25.2) MB, 23.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 1.5 ms in 5 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 55 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.963) finalize incremental m[9161:0x41069d0]    27013 ms: Mark-sweep 23.2 (25.2) -> 22.2 (25.2) MB, 3.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.1 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 168 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental m

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x21639e1c08d1 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: getImageData(this=0x0529133cc801 <CanvasRenderingContext2D map = 0x381c66f8e359>,32150,22958,0,0,0x0529133cc801 <CanvasRenderingContext2D map = 0x381c66f8e359>)

    1: getPoints [0x324589ad9b31] [/var/apps/print-export-worker/getPoints.js:11] [bytecode=0x340f496a0d29 offset=86](this=0x2d04988cd319 <JSGlobal Object>,0x0529133cc801 <CanvasRenderingContext2D map = 0x381c...

FATAL ERROR: v8::ArrayBuffer::New Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: 0xa09830 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa09c55 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb7d71e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb7da99 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xb7db7b  [node]
 6: 0xb9b93e  [node]
 7: 0x7f7f87de455f Context2d::GetImageData(Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/var/apps/print-export-worker/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node]
 8: 0x7f7f87dd91f9  [/var/apps/print-export-worker/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node]
 9: 0xbe96a9  [node]
10: 0xbeb497 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
11: 0x13c5c79  [node]
Aborted
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all I needed to do was to upgrade my node version to 14Lts. There was some limitation in version 12.

Answer (score 0):

The other way of getting the image data from an image without using node-canvas was using sharp like this.

```
sharp(canvas.toBuffer(), { limitInputPixels: false })
  .raw()
  .ensureAlpha()
  .toBuffer()
  .then((img) => {
    let imageData = new Uint8ClampedArray(img)
    return imageData
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('ERROR IN SHARP', err)
    reject(err)
  })
```

It has to use limitInputPixels into false if you are working with large images.